# Set up PHP to work with MySQL on freeBSD?

Tags: php, mysql, freebsd

On my freeBSD machine i installed both php5 and mysql. Both work great independent of eachother, but not together. For example ,when running a simple `mysql_connect`, it says `'undefined function'` Also, on the PHP info page, theres nothing concerning MySQL.

I'm thinking theres an extra step to the php installation to make it work with MySQL.

Any suggestions?

Comment: do a `php -m | grep mysql`, is the mysql module has been installed and enabled ?

Comment: Heres what i get:
`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/overload.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/overload.so" in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/zlib.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/zlib.so" in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/pcre.so' - Cannot open "/usr/local/lib/php/20090626/pcre.so" in Unknown on line 0
mysqlnd`

Comment: belongs on http://serverfault.com/ Q&A for system administrators and desktop support professionals

Comment: @Mchl  Added a question on serverfault.com http://serverfault.com/questions/296758/set-up-php-to-work-with-mysql-on-freebsd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it.

```
sudo portinstall databases/php5-mysql
```